# Set host ip in run parameters Intellij with WSL2

Tags: intellij-idea, grep, wsl-2

I have a run configuration setup for a server tool. I want to run it in WSL2 environment from an Intellij run task. This works great but I need to manually set the Windows host IP whenever I restart the WSL2. To get the host IP I want to use this grep command:

```
 grep -o -P "(?<=nameserver )[0-9\.]+" /etc/resolv.conf
```

I played with the configuration and tried something like this

[image]

This didn't work, because the grep command didn't get executed. It worked as expected when I used it in the console.

Trying the same thing with the enviroment variable didn't succeed as well.

I saw that it is possible to setup a "before run task". Maybe it is possible to do it with this option?

Comment: What is the run configuration type? 'Before run' gives the ability to execute another run configuration before the current on, but it will not let to re-use the previous run configuration results in the current run configuration.

Comment: Try setting up a External tool for it: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-third-party-tools.html

Comment: I couldn't get it done with an external tool. I don't know how